# Is this intensity of Jogging good to reduce fat?

Tags: running, weight-loss, body-fat, jogging

According to a website the speed of Jogging is around 4 to 6 miles per hour, I'm doing something around (very little faster) 4 miles (6.4 Km) per hour, but I'm doing that uphill, so I go 213 feets (65 meters) up per mile (or per 1.6 Km)

I'm 5 ft 4 in (1.63 m) heigth (yeah, I'm pretty small) and I weight 165 pounds (or 75 kg)

The only problem is that running on that hill with that speed and going up that amount of meters... I could maintain that intensity for about 16 minutes, the idea would do that for 40 to 50 minutes to remove fat from my body, is that enough?

Comment: Those questions may initially seem irrelevant, but they're basically about what sort of exercise and diet actually work for reducing fat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remove fat from your body by using more calories than you put in.

Jogging for 20 mins burns around 200 calories (**ish**). Most people need 2200 calories per day. Therefore, you cannot out-exercise a bad diet. If you want to lose weight then focus on **diet** instead of micromanaging the gym activity; doing that will lead you to be more successful.

I looked at running intensity in this question: [What is the "fat burning zone"?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31346/what-is-the-fat-burning-zone)

---

The mantra is true for this question:

## eat less, move more.